# Why use complexType in web service?

Tags: java, php, web-services, wsdl, .net

I just read a book about web servieces at it says there is "RPC style web service" and "Document style web service". the second is using in WSDL sequence and complexType. When should I use this style?

Comment: Just curios, which book did you read

Answer (score 3):

You should use Complex Data Type when you want to transfer data-objects like Contacts, Messages or certain programming objects as it is to client apps in respective technology.

For example if you're using Complex Type webservice built in .NET or Java and you're calling that webservice from PHP or Ruby you will get object from .NET or Java exported as it is (in 98% cases with very minor language specific attributes changed) in PHP or Ruby.

So if you're one of those who don't like simple string, int, bool or array data type you can use Complex Type in your WSDL. It's not very easy to begin with but once you get it started it's fun.

Zend Framework auto-discovery of WSDL can let you generate WSDL automatically from PHP if you're using PHP for developing web services, but if your complexity grows nothing like hand-coding WSDL yourself.

Answer (score 2):

complexType in webservice will be used to represent user defined data types like Objects you want to transfer (not java default types), for example if you have UserVO which contains name, address, phone etc.,, you need to define this as ComplexType in WSDL to send. Java collections/array also treated as complex types. Here is good tutorial on [Types of Webserices](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/) and [example complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377102/soap-wsdl-complextype-being-posted-as-wrong-argument-type).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, just about everybody who's still using SOAP web services (i.e. hasn't migrated over to REST) is using "document style".

The distinction is pretty much meaningless unless you're hand-coding the WSDL.  And who does that ;)?

If you're using tools like Visual Studio or Axis to generate your WSDL, and tools to generate your stubs, then the only thing that really matters is if the code generated by one tool understands the code generated by the other.  Which leads back to "as far as SOAP is concerned, it's pretty much a doc style world".  Or, more specifically, a "document style/literal wrapped" world.

Here are a couple of good links:

- http://mangstacular.blogspot.com/2011/05/wsdl-soap-bindings-confusion-rpc-vs.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/
- [Document or RPC based web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598/document-or-rpc-based-web-services)